# ClamAV not updating - EOL version

Tags: upgrade, updates, lts, clamav

The AV database for ClamAV is not updating anymore. When I looked into the ClamAV documentation it mentioned that any Clam version below 0.103.4 is not supported anymore and blocked from updating as they reached EOL.
I am running Xubuntu 20.04 Fossa LTS. In its packet list, the latest ClamAV version is 0.103.2 (which is also the version running on my system).
Is Ubuntu going to update it or do I need to compile from source code to run the latest version? Any advice on how to proceed and what would be the best practice is much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know how the bug reporting is working. The issue was reported on launchpad on the 26th of Nov '21. Apparently, it hasn't been decided to fix it. At least this is my understanding of its current status. Do you happen to know if there is a safe way to manually upgrade the AV? Many thanks.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem: LTS releases generally DON'T get version bumps (which adds new features and new bugs and breaks workflows). They usually get patched instead, usually using upstream-provided patches. So 20.04 isn't running upstream 0.103.2, it's running 0.103.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, which indicates at least one patch to the original 0.103.2. In Ubuntu the *latest* version may not be fully compatible with your older LTS; you should seek the *latest version compatible with your release*...which is probably what you have. You get your support from Ubuntu anyway, not Clam upstream.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification. I managed to update the version and AV definition manually.